# Golang crypto/tls memory leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, finalizer

**Question:** Why is *tls.Conn not being garbage collected even after the variable goes out of scope, and it's properly closed using the `(*tls.Conn).Close()` method? Full code to reproduce given below.

**Motivation:** I've tried 2 websocket libraries (https://github.com/gorilla/websocket and https://github.com/gobwas/ws) so far as part of long-running service (> 24 hours), which maintains ~10 websocket connections as a client throughout its lifetime. Sometimes they are disconnected from the server, in which case I make a new connection. The memory usage steadily grows throughout its lifetime, and from memory profiles, it points to the underlying *tls.Conn object staying on the heap. (not being garbage collected).

**Full code to reproduce**

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "runtime"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func finalizer(_ interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("finalizer called")
}

func main() {
    // setup interrupt handler
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                tlsConnectThenCloseAfterWait()
            }
        }()
    }

    <-c
    os.Exit(1)

}

func tlsConnectThenCloseAfterWait() {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "mail.google.com:443", &tls.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to connect: " + err.Error())
    }
    defer func() {
        err := conn.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("closing conn failed")
        }
    }()

    runtime.SetFinalizer(conn, finalizer)
    conn.Write([]byte("hello how are you"))

    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second)
    <-timer.C
}
```

Output of `GODEBUG=gctrace=1 ./main`

```
gc 1 @0.088s 1%: 0+9.0+0 ms clock, 0+12/11/0+0 ms cpu, 4->5->1 MB, 5 MB goal, 12 P
gc 2 @0.102s 3%: 0+4.9+0.99 ms clock, 0+5.9/6.0/0+11 ms cpu, 4->4->1 MB, 5 MB goal, 12 P
gc 3 @0.114s 5%: 0+4.9+1.0 ms clock, 0+3.9/10/2.9+12 ms cpu, 4->4->2 MB, 5 MB goal, 12 P
gc 4 @0.171s 4%: 0+5.0+0 ms clock, 0+1.0/9.9/0+0 ms cpu, 4->5->3 MB, 5 MB goal, 12 P
gc 5 @0.196s 4%: 0+5.9+0 ms clock, 0+2.9/9.9/0+0 ms cpu, 5->7->3 MB, 6 MB goal, 12 P
gc 6 @0.352s 2%: 1.0+2.0+0 ms clock, 12+0/1.9/1.9+0 ms cpu, 6->7->4 MB, 7 MB goal, 12 P
gc 7 @0.365s 2%: 0.99+3.0+0 ms clock, 11+3.0/5.0/0+0 ms cpu, 7->8->5 MB, 8 MB goal, 12 P
gc 8 @0.399s 3%: 0+13+0 ms clock, 0+18/29/1.0+0 ms cpu, 9->11->6 MB, 10 MB goal, 12 P
gc 9 @1.278s 1%: 1.0+28+0 ms clock, 12+9.9/53/0+0 ms cpu, 10->13->9 MB, 13 MB goal, 12 P
gc 10 @1.433s 2%: 1.0+22+0 ms clock, 12+45/55/1.0+0 ms cpu, 14->16->9 MB, 18 MB goal, 12 P
gc 11 @1.534s 2%: 0+6.0+0 ms clock, 0+4.0/15/3.0+0 ms cpu, 16->17->11 MB, 19 MB goal, 12 P
gc 12 @2.479s 1%: 0+3.0+0 ms clock, 0+0/6.0/18+0 ms cpu, 20->20->12 MB, 22 MB goal, 12 P
gc 13 @2.656s 1%: 1.0+10+0 ms clock, 12+3.0/30/4.9+0 ms cpu, 23->25->16 MB, 25 MB goal, 12 P
gc 14 @3.737s 1%: 0+6.0+0 ms clock, 0+3.0/18/9.0+0 ms cpu, 31->33->20 MB, 33 MB goal, 12 P
gc 15 @4.830s 0%: 0+5.9+0 ms clock, 0+5.0/13/16+0 ms cpu, 39->40->25 MB, 41 MB goal, 12 P
gc 16 @6.733s 0%: 0.99+16+0.99 ms clock, 11+7.9/47/80+11 ms cpu, 50->50->32 MB, 51 MB goal, 12 P
gc 17 @8.140s 0%: 0.99+21+0 ms clock, 11+3.0/59/125+0 ms cpu, 64->64->42 MB, 65 MB goal, 12 P
gc 18 @11.168s 0%: 1.0+28+0 ms clock, 12+24/78/97+0 ms cpu, 82->82->54 MB, 84 MB goal, 12 P
gc 19 @14.433s 0%: 0.99+27+0 ms clock, 11+9.0/74/146+0 ms cpu, 106->106->70 MB, 108 MB goal, 12 P
gc 20 @18.883s 0%: 0+47+0 ms clock, 0+6.0/133/211+0 ms cpu, 137->138->91 MB, 140 MB goal, 12 P
gc 21 @24.437s 0%: 0.99+30+0.99 ms clock, 11+15/91/101+11 ms cpu, 177->178->118 MB, 182 MB goal, 12 P
gc 22 @31.872s 0%: 1.0+105+0 ms clock, 12+60/317/256+0 ms cpu, 230->233->155 MB, 236 MB goal, 12 P
gc 23 @41.705s 0%: 0+101+0 ms clock, 0+15/283/549+0 ms cpu, 302->303->200 MB, 310 MB goal, 12 P
gc 24 @54.302s 0%: 0+92+0 ms clock, 0+9.0/278/472+0 ms cpu, 390->392->260 MB, 400 MB goal, 12 P
gc 25 @70.777s 0%: 0+38+0 ms clock, 0+4.9/113/321+0 ms cpu, 508->508->337 MB, 521 MB goal, 12 P
gc 26 @92.203s 0%: 0+108+0 ms clock, 0+57/326/391+0 ms cpu, 658->662->442 MB, 675 MB goal, 12 P
gc 27 @120.781s 0%: 2.0+99+0 ms clock, 24+11/292/529+0 ms cpu, 862->864->574 MB, 884 MB goal, 12 P
```

The finalizer is never called, and the memory keeps on growing.

Using `go version go1.15.8 windows/amd64`

Also linked to the github issue here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41987

Comment: Have you noticed that the problem goes away if you don't set any finalizers? So it would seem that your finalizers are the cause of the memory leak. I'm wondering whether they may even prevent `conn` from being GC'd.

Comment: Totally missed that, good catch. I'm not familiar with runtime calls so I'm probably doing something very wrong with the finalizer. Although I'm still facing memory leaks when I'm using the websocket libraries I mentioned, will try to make a reproducible version of that.

Comment: I will once I get 15 reputation points :)

Comment: You may be clobbering a finalizer that’s intended to clean up the objects that are leaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misusing `runtime.SetFinalizer`; here is what [the doc](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) says:

> The [first argument] **must be a pointer** to an object allocated by calling `new`, by taking the address of a composite literal, or by taking the address of a local variable.

(my emphasis)

If I pass `&conn` (rather than `conn` itself) to `runtime.SetFinalizer`, the finalizers do get called and the heap never exceeds 8 MB:

```
$ GODEBUG=gctrace=1 ./main
gc 1 @1.789s 0%: 0.041+0.67+0.018 ms clock, 0.33+0.31/1.0/2.3+0.14 ms cpu, 4->4->1 MB, 5 MB goal, 8 P
gc 2 @1.874s 0%: 0.044+0.69+0.015 ms clock, 0.35+0.20/1.0/2.4+0.12 ms cpu, 4->4->2 MB, 5 MB goal, 8 P
gc 3 @1.880s 0%: 0.064+0.79+0.014 ms clock, 0.51+0.22/1.1/2.3+0.11 ms cpu, 4->4->2 MB, 5 MB goal, 8 P
gc 4 @1.887s 0%: 0.14+1.5+0.080 ms clock, 1.1+1.6/2.5/0+0.64 ms cpu, 5->5->3 MB, 6 MB goal, 8 P
gc 5 @1.904s 0%: 0.097+1.1+0.025 ms clock, 0.77+1.0/1.9/2.6+0.20 ms cpu, 6->6->3 MB, 7 MB goal, 8 P
gc 6 @1.974s 0%: 0.12+1.7+0.12 ms clock, 0.99+1.4/2.9/1.2+0.98 ms cpu, 6->7->3 MB, 7 MB goal, 8 P
gc 7 @2.900s 0%: 0.22+1.9+0.025 ms clock, 1.8+5.7/2.9/0+0.20 ms cpu, 7->7->4 MB, 8finalizer called
 MB goal, 8finalizer called
 P
finalizer called
finalizer called
finalizer called
finalizer called
finalizer called
finalizer called
--snip--
```

Compiling the program with `-gcflags="-m"` reveals that local variable `conn` gets moved to the heap. I'm no finalizer expert (by far), but I suspect that your misuse of `runtime.SetFinalizer` causes the retention of a reference to the `conn` variable, thereby making each instance of it ineligible for garbage collection, hence the memory leak.

It's unclear to me why you'd want to use finalizers anyway; conventional wisdom is that [finalizers are best avoided](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-finalizers-786df8e17687).